# Angular ngx-quill editor - handle image click

Tags: angular, ngx-quill

I have images inserted into the editor content area and I need to handle these images clicks.
I need to know what the image was clicked on.

Whether is this possible, how do I do this? Just the idea.

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
  @HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
  handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (event?.target['src']) {
      this.handleEditorImageClick(event);
    }
  }
```